# Am I able to link another HTML file in another html?

Tags: html

I currently have a `pageMaster` file which is an HTML file. I am trying to keep it clean. I am linking my javascript files to this `pageMaster` for example `<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/mainpage.js"></script>`. I would like to link an HTML page this pageMaster to avoid having a clutter. Is this possible?

This is what i'm attempting `<script="text/javascript" src="/resources/state-icons.html"></script>` but it is not receiving back the icons I am expecting

Comment: I'm really not clear what you are asking, but an HTML document isn't any kind of `script` and certainly isn't `text/javascript`. If you want a template for shared chunks of HTML, then use a template language and either server side programming or a build time preprocessor AKA static site generator.

Comment: Why do you want to link the html? Do you want to reuse it like a template? E.g. every page has the same footer code?

Comment: I don't want to reuse it as a template. Its just that the code needed to generate the icons i'd like to use is over a thousand long code of text. So to avoid having the pageMaster HTML file cluttered i'd like to have the code in a body tag on another file and import it into my pageMaster file.

Answer (score 0):

Since html isn't a script, you can't load it as an script (using `<script type="text/javascript">` does't make a lot of sense, does it?).

You have to use a preprocessing language, like php, which will build the output on the server. Using php, you could have something like:

```
<p>Some html
<?=file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/resources/state-icons.html')?>
...more html...</p>
```

Or:

```
<?php
include(__DIR__.'/header.php');
?>
...html...
```

If you can't or don't want to use a server-side language, you can do this with javascript. You can download the contents of the other page and insert them wherever you want (I will use jQuery just because it's easy to write, you don't actually *need* it):

HTML:

```
<span class="some-placeholder-for-state-icons"></span>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $.get('/resources/state-icons.html',function(html) {
        $(".some-placeholder-for-state-icons").html(html);
    });
});
```

Of course, this way will be slower and produce more requests per page view. Which one is better depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do something like this with html. This is possible only for javascript file or stylesheets (css)